# How to install python 2.7.4 on OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: python, osx-mountain-lion

I tried installing python 2.7.4 by overwriting the native Apple's installation of python 2.7 by following [this link](http://wolfpaulus.com/jounal/mac/installing_python_osx) (wolfpaulus.com), and as a result both easy_install and pip no longer work.

[This link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3842421?start=0&tstart=0) (apple.com) suggests the native Apple bundle should never be deleted.

Is it possible to restore python 2.7 supplied by Apple without reinstalling OSX?
Is there a definitive guide to upgrading python to 2.7.4 on OSX Lion? For instance, before breaking my set up I could install bumpy, django into 2.7.4, but matplotlib refused to install to anything but 2.7, either from binaries or source.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is absolutely not a good idea to replace Apples default python installation. If you have done, then you could try with the following command

" brew install python --framework "

R

Comment: Though so, but then how come so many grateful comments on wolfpaulus site?

Comment: They are misinformed.  It *is* very bad advice.  I've posted a comment there to that effect (awaiting moderation).

Comment: Unfortunately, `brew` will not restore the system Python framework.

Comment: Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
    The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
    You can try again using `brew link python'

Answer (score 2):

You should never remove anything in `/System/Library` or `/usr` (other than `/usr/local`). Files installed in those locations are managed by Apple as part of OS X. At worst you can fatally damage your OS X system; at best you are at risk of all of your changes being wiped out by the next software update. In particular with Python, you’ve just wiped out Apple-supplied extensions to Python that are not available elsewhere. The right way to update a system component like Python is to install the new version at a different location, like the python.org Python installers do in `/Library/Frameworks`, and then manage access by modifying your shell `PATH` environment variable.  Unfortunately, Apple does not make it easy to install individual components of OS X that have been mistakenly removed.  To properly restore all of the system Python that you've deleted, the easiest approach is to reinstall OS X itself.

When you install another version of Python, you should also use it to install additional versions of `pip` or `easy_install`.  Generally, each Python version should have its own version of each.

Comment: Thanks, will re-download and re-install OSX overnight.

Comment: Also - how do you tell a mtplotlib distributable which environment to install to? I think by default it uses Apple's.

Comment: The general idea with installing Python add-ons is to use the desired Python instance during the install.  If it has a `setup.py` script, run that from the desired Python.  If it recommends using `easy_install` or `pip`, use the version you've installed for the desired Python.

Comment: Does this look correct now? 
    which python
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
    python -V
Python 2.7.4

Comment: Thanks, reinstalling Xcode did help. Not touching /usr/bin/ anytime soon.